# Cannot install SQL Server (2012) PowerPivot for SharePoint, always fails Sharepoint Version check

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Trying to install a fresh install of `Sharepoint 2010 (w/ SP1)` and `SQL Server 2012 PowerPivot for Sharepoint`.

The prerequisites clearly show that `Sharepoint 2010 SP1` is needed, which we have installed.  However after when trying to install the SQL Server portion we consistently fail the rule `SharePoint version requirement for PowerPivot for SharePoint' validation in the`SQL Server` install process.

Here is the process we are following:

1. install Sharepoint 2010
2. install Sharepoint 2010 SP1
3. install SQL Server 2012 PowerPivot for SharePoint

Here is a screen shot of the error and the log file error.  We are completely stuck at this point, anyone run into this before?

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**

[This Article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldensetup/thread/30dbbdc6-56ab-47b1-92e3-f26fc20aa157) mentions an issue with the eval version of Sharepoint 2010 not correctly inserting the version into the registry but it does not mention how to fix this or work around..... if this helps anyone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked over at [SharePoint StackExchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/50090/cannot-install-sql-server-2012-powerpivot-for-sharepoint-always-fails-sharepo) and found the answer.

The enterprise evaluation is missing all the necessary registry entries to install PowerPivot.  Following [this blog entry](https://andrewwhitten.wordpress.com/2012/10/27/sharepoint-2013-powerpivot-install-issue-please-install-sharepoint-before-you-install-powerpivot-for-sharepoint/) you can add the necessary registry entries and proceed with the install.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install SharePoint Standard or Enterprise Edition?  PowerPivot requires that SharePoint be Enterprise Edition.

Comment: We did the Enterprise edition, but only the evaluation version (we want to get it up and running and make sure it is what we want before we drop 5k on a license).

Comment: I did find [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldensetup/thread/30dbbdc6-56ab-47b1-92e3-f26fc20aa157) that mentions an issue with the eval version of Sharepoint, but doesnt mention how to fix/workaround

Comment: Looks like there are two eval builds.  One which is standard and one which is enterprise.  I found this in the dropdown on here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/ee388573.aspx

Comment: We definitely have the Enterprise Edition.  Hrmmm.  Do you have 2010 EE installed?  If so Im wondering if you can snap a screen shot of your registry entry for the version (Ill have to dig up the path for you)

Comment: Won't help any, I don't have access to a site which has PowerView installed.  I've built it in classes dozens of times with students, haven't had anyone ask me to build it in the real world for them, yet.